# Did Lt Gruber ever find out that he didn't kill René?

Tags: allo-allo

In one of the first episodes of the *Allo Allo*, the main character - René Artois - is sentenced to death by firing squad led by Lieutenant Gruber. Fortunately for René, Germans are given wooden bullets (which apparently splinter after leaving the gun barrel), but Gruber, who always fancied the fat café owner, doesn't know that.

To cover his survival, from now on, René pretends to be his own twin brother, *also* called René. It seems that almost everyone knows that this is a paper-thin disguise... except for Gruber, who is always visibly upset whenever someone reminds him about "shooting René"

Did Lt Gruber ever find out that he didn't kill anyone?

Comment: I haven't seen this show, but when only a character "believes" (ignores) something that all of the others know for being false, it's a comic effect like "the idiot" that makes everybody laugh because that character is digging deeper and deeper (like Gruber being upset for René to be dead while all of the others know he's alive).  Especially when linked to a "*paper-thin disguise*" as you mention.

Comment: @OldPadawan - though it was a 'standard' british sitcom, it was actually far more clever than that. One of the few ever to have an actual long plot - which led to an early breaking the 4th wall to recap each episode start. It also had interminable plot devices to find, lose, swap, counterfeit, lose again, rediscover items & characters. Also, because the characters spoke 4 languages, few of them could understand each other… though the entire dialog is in English [including one who was an English spy, speaking French with a 'bad accent'.. still in English] (You probably had to be there;)

Comment: Yasskier - idk whether it was ever revead in the original series, but did you see the much later final, final episode from 2004 - [The Return of 'Allo 'Allo!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Return_of_%27Allo_%27Allo!) which did put the lid on some of the bits of open plot. Too long ago for me to remember details now. Gruber is in the episode, at least.

Comment: @Tetsujin: ho I wasn't belittling the show or the character at all :) BBC broadcast are usually world class programs. I was just thinking about that kind of effect, maybe shouldn't have said "the idiot". I read a lot about the show when I saw this question and it seems of very good quality.

Comment: @OldPadawan Gruber was never the "idiot" of the show - he was actually a highly educated and sensitive artist. He was a bit feminine - "playing gay for laughs" with a huge crush on Rene (but in the "After the war" episode, we can see that he is happily married to a woman)

Answer (score 1):

### No!

As you say, [René Artois](https://alloallo.fandom.com/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Artois) escapes a death sentence and then [poses as his own twin brother](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BackupTwin), "René 2". [Two characters are kept in the dark](https://alloallo.fandom.com/wiki/The_Funeral) about this deception: Lieutenant Hubert Gruber (who led the firing squad) and Herr Flick, the vindictive Gestapo officer.

The deception is maintained so that the German high command do not realize their mistake and re-arrest René to finish the job!

His 'death' sets up some problems for René as [Edith inherits his money and the café](https://alloallo.fandom.com/wiki/The_Wooing_of_Widow_Artois). René tries at first to engineer a remarriage but (despite [some very near misses](https://alloallo.fandom.com/wiki/Awful_Wedded_Wife)) this has not happened by the end of the last series. On the other hand, the way is opened to [eventually elope](https://alloallo.fandom.com/wiki/A_Winkle_In_Time) with his waitress/mistress Yvette.

Although Gruber sincerely believes that he has had René shot, he seems to [move on to 'René 2'](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ReplacementGoldfish) almost as easily as the other characters, [quickly developing the same crush on the 'new' René](https://alloallo.fandom.com/wiki/Swiftly_and_with_Style).

We never see Gruber's notion that he has had René shot corrected. The two men have a final talk after the war in [The Return of 'Allo 'Allo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eU2lwwth06k) but do not speak of the matter even then. Nevertheless Gruber is still *mad about ze boy...*